# Persisting CUDA error with tensorflow in WSL

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to make tensorflow use my NVIDIA GTX 1060 gpu in my laptop. I created a python environment and installed tensorflow, python, pip, etc. I am using Ubuntu on Windows (so wsl-ubuntu). On CMD, the nvidia-smi command is showing my GPU. But with tensorflow, I get the following error:

```
2022-01-26 21:45:36.677191: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:271] failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE: no CUDA-capable device is detected
2022-01-26 21:45:36.678074: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:156] kernel driver does not appear to be running on this host (DESKTOP-P8QAQC0): /proc/driver/nvidia/version does not exist
Num GPUs Available:  0
```

I have CUDA 11.5 and 11.6 installed, with cudNN 8.3.2.44 installed. I manually copied and pasted the files into the CUDA directory and ran the exe (exe didn't seem to install files though). I am not sure what else to do. Help would be really appreciated!

EDIT: I'm on Windows 10, and I changed my CUDA installation to 11.2 and cuDNN 8.1. The issue is still there. Both are installed on my C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA. I'm not sure if that's the error, since I didn't install directly on WSL.

Comment: You have the wrong versions of CUDA installed for the Tensorflow build you are using. Tensorflow builds are strictly versioned and require specific versions of CUDA -- see https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#tested_build_configurations .

Comment: @talonmies Thanks for the comment. I changed it to CUDA 11.2 with cuDNN 8.1, but the same error exists.

Comment: I don't understand. You say you are using WSL (GPU virtualization is only supported in WSL2) and you show CUDA toolkits install on a Windows path, not a linux path.

Comment: Other than the driver (installed on the windows side; you don't install a driver on the linux side) nothing in your windows environment impacts CUDA in your linux environment.  The CUDA toolkits  you installed or didn't install on the windows side have no bearing on the behavior of CUDA on the linux side.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I've installed NVIDIA drivers on Windows host system, and there're CUDA .so files in /usr/lib/wsl inside WSL2